# call JQuery UI datepicker through a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datepicker

How to call datepicker using function. when i click on the calendar image the datepicker will show with 2months.

```
<tr><td>date</td><td>
            <input type='text' readonly name="SDATE" id='SDATE' ><img src="calendar.gif" border='0' id='dat_img' onclick="return showCalendar('SDATE')" >
        </td></tr><tr><td>date</td><td>
            <input type='text' readonly name="SDATE1" id='SDATE1' ><img src="calendar.gif" border='0' id='dat_img' onclick="return showCalendar('SDATE1')" >
        </td></tr><tr><td>date</td><td>
            <input type='text' readonly name="SDATE2" id='SDATE3' ><img src="calendar.gif" border='0' id='dat_img' onclick="return showCalendar('SDATE3')" >
        </td></tr>

    <script>
    function showCalendar(inputId){
        //alert(inputId);
        for(i=0;i<=inputId.length;$i++){
            $( "#"+inputId).datepicker({
                numberOfMonths: 2,
                dayNamesMin: ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'],
                changeYear:true,
                changeMonth: true,
                autoSize: true
            });
        }
    }
    </script>
```

this function is not working.

Comment: use the methods that are shown in the documentation. Adding your own event handler doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0):

Use a common class is good instead of different `id` like,

```
$(function(){
    $('.mydatepicker').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        dayNamesMin: ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'],
        changeYear:true,
        changeMonth: true,
        autoSize: true
    });
});
```

Then, your **HTML** should look like,

```
<tr>
    <td>date</td>
    <td>
        <input type='text' class="mydatepicker" readonly name="SDATE" id='SDATE' />
        <img src="calendar.gif" border='0' id='dat_img' />
    </td>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td>date</td>
    <td>
        <input type='text' class="mydatepicker" readonly name="SDATE1" id='SDATE1' />
        <img src="calendar.gif" border='0' id='dat_img' />
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>date</td>
    <td>
        <input type='text' class="mydatepicker" readonly name="SDATE2" id='SDATE3' />
        <img src="calendar.gif" border='0' id='dat_img' />
    </td>
 </tr>
```

To Use [#date-range](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range) you can use class in a tr-row like

```
$(".from-date").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.to-date').datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
$(".to-date").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.from-date').datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
```

**[Date-range Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/5dsygycv/7/)**

Comment: you can use `data-*` attribute for this and change accordingly.

Comment: you need minDate and maxDate for each element?

Comment: i need like this (but using class name): http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Comment: @test10php see my updated answer and [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/5dsygycv/7/). I added `from-date` and `to-date` for the input element where the `date range` needed.

Answer (score 0):

Rather tell the controls that they are date pickers when the page loads (on document ready).
First you will need to select all the controls that you want as date pickers. So we will select all controls who's name starts with 'SDATE':

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("input[name^='SDATE']").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        autoSize: true
    });
});
```

Alternatively you can try to add.show() at the end:

```
function showCalendar(inputId){
    //alert(inputId);
    for(i=0;i<=inputId.length;$i++){
        $( "#"+inputId).datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            dayNamesMin: ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'],
            changeYear:true,
            changeMonth: true,
            autoSize: true
        }).show();/*Note the change here*/
    }
}
```